# $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] not define in my phpinfo

Tags: php

When I am looking my php info (php 7.1) I haven't `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` and `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']`

How to have the element of `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` and  `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']` or equivalent.

Thank you.

Comment: $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] is not displayed very often. You have to user other $_SERVER values to get the info you want. There is a bunch to choose from.

Comment: Which URL are you calling which executes the `phpinfo();` file? Also, what do you think the value of `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` do?

Answer (score 1):

this display the value of  $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] only when there is any get params in url ..

```
 E.G :http://www.example.com/page/abc.php/hello
```

now for above url if u print `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` in abc.php then it will display "hello"

Comment: Assuming OP is using Apache, they also need the [`AcceptPathInfo`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) directive to be "On" or "Default"

Comment: Err, _where_ its value is set doesn't matter. It just has to be "On" or "Default"